# peer or orderer reload after reenroll

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, blockchain

I want to know how to reload a peer (or an orderer) after I reenrolled MSP from CA server.

Currently I do it with the following procedure. The MSP resides in the host and mounted to the container.

1. docker stop 'target peer'.
2. docker rm 'target peer'.
3. reenroll.
4. docker run 'target peer'.

Is there a way to reload a reenrolled MSP without stopping peer or orderer?